# Javascript eval() not always working on text appended to contents of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, eval

I use AJAX to load dynamic content to `#main_content` element:

```
var con = document.getElementById('main-content');
con.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

However, `innerHTML` does not run JS in `script` elements. To evaluate them, I use

```
$("#main-content").find("script").each(function(i) {
  eval($(this).text());
  console.log($(this).text);
});
```

One of my loaded pages has the following `<script>` element which gets executed, and works as expected:

```
<!-- AJAX response -->
<script>alert(123);</script>
```

However, if I define functions in the AJAX request, they come up as undefined when I attempt to call them:

```
<!-- AJAX response -->
<script>
function func() {
  alert(123);
}
</script>
```

I am not sure why the first `<script>` element gets evaluated and executed, and the second one does not. They are both being called by the same function to load and evaluate the contents of the div.

Comment: You would need global `eval` for that

Comment: Im sorry, whats global eval vs eval?

Comment: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in non-strict mode, global variables evaluated by a [direct `eval` call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.1.1) become local variables of the scope which called `eval`:

```
var code = "var foo = 123";
(function() {
  eval(code); // direct call
  foo; // 123
})();
foo; // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

In strict mode there are some [restricctions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2.1), so the variable in not created in the local scope neither.

Instead, if you want the variables to become global, you can use an indirect eval call:

```
var code = "var foo = 123";
(function() {
  window.eval(code); // indirect call
  foo; // 123
})();
foo; // 123
```

This is explained in [10.4.2 - Entering Eval Code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2).

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I don't understand why eval isn't working on the window, but ill take it!